# Why are wheels labeled "R16" when the 16" is actually the diameter?

Tags: tires, wheels

Just wondering about this, unless the R doesn't mean "Radius" it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: R is of course for round as opposed to S16 square wheels ;)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Tires (or tyres) are marked as `www/hhRdd` where `www` is the tread width in mm, `hh` is the sidewall height as a percentage of width and `dd` is the inner diameter in inches. I.e. 245/75R16 has a width of 24.5cm, 75% (~18cm) height and 16in (~40cm) diameter. The R indicates the construction of the tire is 'radial' ply. 'Bias ply' tires, which were common before radials became the standard are indicated with a blank space. Other tire constructions exist, but are rarely used on highway vehicles.

Points to anyone who can give a good reason for mixing three different systems of measurement in a single size.

> "The code also usually has a prefix indicating whether it for a car, truck, etc - also there seems to often be lots of non-standard suffixes for manufacturer date, load & speed ratings etc" -Wilf

Great point. Much more information about tyre sizes can be found here:
http://www.tirebuyer.com/education/understanding-tire-sizes-and-types

Comment: At a guess, default rim diameters were established somewhere in the middle of the 20th century, before metrification became the norm.    There's nothing stopping anyone making metric-sized rims, except there are no tyres because there are no metric rims.   Same reason bicycle chain is 1/2" pitch, because that is simply what it is.

Comment: The code also usually has a prefix indicating whether it for a car, truck, etc - also there seems to often be lots of non-standard suffixes for manufacturer date, load & speed ratings etc

Comment: I really wish manufacturers simplified their sidewall height to a static measurement. It would certainly make things easier when trying to maintain overall circumference while going with wider tires for, say, an AWD vehicle. Instead, I have to math and then determine if the height difference is an acceptable tolerance or not.

Comment: @Criggie: well, not really true, there are: Michelin TRX (and related). Not very widespread any more but it existed and still exists.

Comment: @Criggie it's too bad default rim diameters weren't established at the turn of the 20th century.  Still trying to find some 75/85R30s to put on my Infiniti

Comment: Great answer! +1. However, I would mention in the answer that the standard tire type used to be bias ply in the past before radial tires became common.

Comment: that must be a weird looking tire @TrevorD